# is there something wrong with my writing code?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

im beginer in program

i try get data from other model in CI3

can help me for fix this error?

the error

> Message: Undefined variable: data
> Filename: sale/sale_form.php
> Line Number: 274

My view:

```
 <?php foreach ($data as $i => $data) { ?>
    <tr>
     <td><?=$data->barcode ?></td>
      <td><?=$data->name ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

my controller:

```
$this->load->model('item_m');
$item = $this->item_m->get()->result();
$data = ['item' => $item];
$this->template->load('template','transaction/sale/sale_form', $data);
```

my model item:

```
public function get($id = null)
        {
        $this->db->select('p_item.*,p_category.name as category_name, p_unit.name as  unit_name');
        $this->db->from('p_item');
        $this->db->join('p_category','p_category.category_id = p_item.category_id');
        $this->db->join('p_unit','p_unit.unit_id = p_item.unit_id');
        if($id != null) {
            $this->db->where('item_id', $id);
        }
        $this->db->order_by('barcode','asc');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query;
        }
```

pls help me for fix this error

im stuck here, and i decide ask in here

Answer (score 1):

In controller, you should replace

```
$data = ['item' => $item];
```

to

```
$data = ['data' => $item];
```

---

Or

```
$item = $this->item_m->get()->result();
$this->template->load('template','transaction/sale/sale_form', array('data' => $item));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
## from your controller ##
$data = ['item' => $item];
$this->template->load('template','transaction/sale/sale_form', $data);

## your view should be ##
<?php foreach ($item as $i => $data) : ?>
<?php endforeach: ?>
```

`$data = ['item' => $item];`
from your controller you can access your data by **print_r($data['item']);**
but from your view/template you access it by the array name hence, **print_r($item);**

`$data['itemData'] = $item;`
from controller, **print_r($data['itemData']);**
from your view/template, **print_r($itemData);**

> http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/views.html

Comment: Hi John! Would you mind editing your answer and adding a few words of explanation?